# Python: Nested List Indexing Error

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
result = []
for big in aisle:
  for small in big:
    if len(small) >= 0:
        result.append(small[1])
print(np.result)
```

**I've been getting this error: "string index out of range"**

I added in the if statement to make sure each list within the lists under aisle have at least 2 items but still am getting this error. aisle is a list containing lists. the goal is to create a new list only containing the second item in each list within aisle. Of course it would be easier to do using numpy and arrays but want to learn...

Comment: What does `aisle` look like?

Answer (score 0):

`len(small) >= 0` is always true - nothing can have **less** than 0 elements. To have an element with index 1, `small` must be at least 2 elements long (`small[0]` and `small[1]`), so you should test for `len(small) > 1`

Answer (score -1):

Python list indexing is 0 based, my guess is that small might have only one item.

```
result = []
for big in aisle:
  for small in big:
    if len(small) > 0: # >= 0 is always true
        result.append(small[0]) # Here if len(small) === 1 the item is at small[0]
print(result)
```

Comment: Where does your `np.result` come from?

Comment: @Błotosmętek the same place from OP's example?

Comment: @Błotosmętek I just copied OP's example and edited my best guess of what should be changed, np.result comes from OP

Comment: …which makes no sense whatsoever, and clearly is OP's mistake (possibly a leftover from more complicated code).

Comment: I agree, but since I had not idea what that came from I decided to leave as was. Anyway, edited.